# Sum of binomial $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\binom{ n+1}{k}\binom{n}{r}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I want to find(?) derive(?) obtain(?) closed formula for

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\binom{ n+1}{k}\binom{n}{r}$$

Actually for some integers I found this as $2^{2n}$ ....

My first trial is using double sum technique in [$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{l} (-1)^{k-l} s_l ?= \sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=l}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l}s_l $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305143/sum-k-0n-sum-l-0k-binomnk-binomkl-1k-l-s-l-sum-l-0)

and then via mathematica by some $n$,

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \sum_{r=0}^{k-1}  \begin{pmatrix}
n+1 \\
k
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
n  \\
r
\end{pmatrix}
=  \sum_{r=0}^{n+1} \sum_{k=r+1}^{n+1} \begin{pmatrix}
n+1 \\
k
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
n\\
r
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
But still does not have explicit form...

[image]

Comment: It is equal to $\sum_{0\le r<k\le n+1} \binom{n+1}{k}\binom{n}{r}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of products of combinatorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324706/sum-of-products-of-combinatorials)

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio, Oh thanks!